# Server-Sent Events not working on Vercel / NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel, server-sent-events

I have a NextJS application that I host on Vercel and I've just added a chat functionality. Because of Vercel's limitations when it comes to sockets (and because this is just a proof of concept) I decided to stream the messages at 1-second intervals. Everything is working well on localhost but I'm getting 504 errors on production and the application doesn't receive a single streaming event.

Here is my code:

```
// pages/api/chat.ts

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { REDIS } from "@/serverApi";

const MAX_RUNS = 30;
const REFRESH_INTERVAL = 1000;

export const config = {
  maxDuration: 60,
};

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log("STARTING");
  let lastTimestamp = Number(req.query.lastTimestamp) || 0;
  const topic = (req.query.topic as string) || "";

  let count = 0;

  res.writeHead(200, {
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Content-Encoding": "none",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-transform",
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
  });

  const interval = setInterval(async () => {
    console.log("GETTING MESSAGES");
    const newMessages = await REDIS.getChatMessages({
      topic,
      fromTimestamp: lastTimestamp + 1,
    });

    console.log("NEW MESSAGES", newMessages);
    if (newMessages.length > 0) {
      lastTimestamp = newMessages[newMessages.length - 1].timestamp;
      res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(newMessages)}\n\n`);
    }

    count += 1;

    if (count > MAX_RUNS) {
      console.log("ENDING");
      clearInterval(interval);
      res.end();
      return;
    }
  }, REFRESH_INTERVAL);

  res.on("close", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    res.end();
  });

  res.socket?.on("close", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    res.end();
  });
};

export default handler;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Getting 504 errors in a production environment when you're trying to stream messages in a Next.js application hosted on Vercel that it does not support. You can read more here:
https://vercel.com/docs/limits/overview#websockets

So, if you send a request every second, you reach Vercel limitation also! You can read more here:
https://vercel.com/docs/limits/overview#rate-limit-examples

A better offer is to use other hosting like AWS, Google Cloud, or Heroku that might offer more flexibility in this regard.